# Building Mozilla : "Abort : Premature EOF reading chunk" error

Tags: browser, mercurial, mozilla

I need to build the mozilla source in my Windows 7 machine. I used the following command line code to pull the source using mercurial

```
hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/ D:\FFsrc\src20
```

but the process always stop in the middle, with the following error.

> requesting all changes adding
>   changesets transaction abort! rollback
>   completed abort: premature EOF reading
>   chunk `<got 6 bytes, expected 776>`

Comment: I just tried cloning the repository, absolutely no problems on my side. Are you sure the problem is related to mercurial and not some network issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI Tonfa, Krtek

the issue was actually on the network, which stopped the clone process. I have now downloaded the bundle and grabbed the source by unbundling it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Source_Code_%2528Mercurial%2529%23

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try successive clone -r, it looks like your connection is flaky which stops the clone process in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I had that error and found it was caused by using the old 1.2 hg client. 
Upgraded to 2.4.2 and it worked fine since then. 
So try to update to the latest hg version.